# How to match a discriminated union type to intended case in pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I am new to F#. I have these type definitions as shown below.

```
type pos = int*int
type value = Red | Green | Blue | Yellow | Black
type piece = value*pos
type state = piece list
```

I want to give my function testColor a state type, and it should return a state type. The length of the state type, will always be length = 3. My testColor function is here:

```
let testColor (column: state) : state =
    let (x1,(y1,z1)) = column[0]
    let (x2,(y2,z2)) = column[1]
    let (x3,(y3,z3)) = column[2]
    let (id) = x2
    match id with
        | x1 -> [((nextColor x1),(y1,z1))]@[(x3,(y2,z2))]
        | x3 -> [(x1,(y1,z1))]@[(nextColor x2,(y2,z2))]
        |_ -> column
```

The nextColor function is the following:

```
let nextColor (v:value) : value =
    match v with
        | Red -> Green
        | Green -> Blue
        | Blue -> Yellow
        | Yellow -> Black
        | Black -> Black
```

I assume the problem is in the pattern matching in testColor. I want to match the name of the value type with other names of the same value type. It seems like it always match to the first case. I can't figure out how to get it to match to the next cases. I have tried to "unpack" x2, since it is the value in x2 I want to compare to x1 and x3.

I tried with the following state type as input:

```
[(Red,(0,0));(Green,(1,0));(Green,(2,0))]
```

My expected output should be this:

```
[(Red,(0,0));(Blue,(1,0))].
```

However, the output given from the function was:

```
[(Blue, (0,0)); (Green, (1, 0))]
```

So it seems like it doesn't match to the second case, which I would want it to do in this example. I hope somebody can help me on the problem.

Comment: Your code is well formatted, and you have defined the types which is good. I believe the issue is that you cannot state in English the problem you want to solve. So there is no specification beyond a single example (from which is it hard to guess a spec) that would allow you or anyone here to write code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is in the pattern matching logic. When writing a pattern matching clause, using e.g. `x3` does not check for equality, but instead assigns the matched value to this new symbol:

```
match id with
| x1 -> [((nextColor x1),(y1,z1))]@[(x3,(y2,z2))]
| x3 -> [(x1,(y1,z1))]@[(nextColor x2,(y2,z2))]
|_ -> column
```

Here, the first case always matches and it assigns the value of `id` to `x1`. You could do something like this instead:

```
match id with
| _ when id = x1 -> [((nextColor x1),(y1,z1))]@[(x3,(y2,z2))]
| _ when id = x3 -> [(x1,(y1,z1))]@[(nextColor x2,(y2,z2))]
|_ -> column
```

But in fact, it is easier to just use `if`:

```
if id = x1 then [((nextColor x1),(y1,z1))]@[(x3,(y2,z2))]
elif id = x3 then [(x1,(y1,z1))]@[(nextColor x2,(y2,z2))]
else column
```